# Delphi11におけるAndroid開発環境構築でのエラー

Tags: android, delphi

delphiを使ってAndroidアプリの作成を試したく
コードを描くのはdelphi、エミュレータのみAndroid studioを使って環境を作っています。

しかし、ハローワールドにたどり着けないです。

ハローワールドのコードをdelphiで作成後、実行しても下記エラーが出ます。

```
プロセスを生成できません。(~~~apkファイルの場所~~~)をインストールできません。
Androidデバイスは選択されたターゲット プラットフォーム アーキテクチャをサポートしていません
```

検索をかけましたが、状況に合う記事を見つけれなかったため助力いただけますと幸いです。

環境:
delphi 11
SDK 25.2.5 64bit

AndroidStudio(多分最新)

試したこと:
エミュレータ側のAPIレベルを下げる。
PC再起動。
SDK再インストール。